# Getting Null Object reference on Edittext

Tags: java, android-edittext

I know that this question looks similar to others on SO but i have tried all the suggestions in the other similar questions and haven't had any success.

I'm getting this error:

```
2020-08-03 20:41:21.372 8916-8916/com.example.spacing E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.spacing, PID: 8916
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.spacing/com.example.spacing.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:159)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:157)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:675)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:692)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:214)
        at com.example.spacing.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:15)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:41)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2020-08-03 20:41:21.411 8916-8916/com.example.spacing I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8916 SIG: 9
```

on this code:

```
    package com.example.spacing;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        public int firstValue;
        EditText first;
        String firstString;
    
    
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            first = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstNum);
            firstString = first.getText().toString();
    
            Button Go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goButton);
            Go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    
                        firstValue = Integer.parseInt(firstString);
                        System.out.print(firstValue);
                }

        });
    }


}
```

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.898" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/FirstAttribute"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/spacedMaterial"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/goButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/firstNum"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.457"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.043" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstNum"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/inMM"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/FirstAttribute"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.934"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/FirstAttribute"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.476" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondAttribute"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/amount"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/goButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.073"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.131" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/secondNumber"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/number"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/secondAttribute"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.934"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/secondAttribute" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thirdAttribute"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/areaWidth"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/goButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.068"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.218" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/thirdNumber"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
      android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/inMM"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/thirdAttribute"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.934"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/thirdAttribute"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.476"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Suggestions i have tried:

I have tried changing the init for the edit text to before and after on-create.
I have made sure that all ids are correct and are referencing the right thing.

And about 5 other things that i cant recall but none of them worked when i tried to build.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you did not leave out some variable initialization in class `MainActivity` in line 15 in the code you posted? It seems you are calling `findViewById` outside of `onCreate`.

Comment: show us your layout xml please

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. if you have a look the 'findviewbyid' is in the 'oncreate'. Unless I;'m mistaken.

Comment: Seems like there is a problem with the theme. In stack trace it seems tries to getTheme() from ContextThemeWrapper but it can't so there is a crash. Can you plese show us how you set your activity up in the AndroidManifest.xml and show us your styles.xml please

Comment: Your stack trace shows the problem is in line 15 of `MainActivity`, during class initialization (this is before `onCreate` is called).

Comment: Agree with @Henry. It seems your code was field initialization as `EditText first = findViewById()` Hence the crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is:
you are trying to initialize the "firstString" variable OUTSIDE of the click listener and as soon as the Activity is created, which means the variable will always be a null object because you did not actually write something in the EditText.

Simply initialize the String inside the ClickListener!

`   package com.example.spacing;

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public int firstValue;
    EditText first;
    String firstString;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        first = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstNum);
        

        Button Go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goButton);
        Go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    firstString = first.getText().toString();
                    firstValue = Integer.parseInt(firstString);
                    System.out.print(firstValue);
            }

    });
}
```

}`

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion? It is not consistent with the stack trace.

Comment: Yes. doesn't make sense but he is right. would like to know how you figured it out.

Comment: Is it because after `onclick`the fields should be filled. (Which they should). so they done return null?

Comment: Yes, it's because of that.In the layout xml you do not delcare a android:text for your EditText view. When the Activity starts the app tries to get a String immediately but there's actually nothing to get. When you click the button, on the other hand, you are supposed to have filled the EditText with something, so the app CAN get something from it. Of course, you could add a condition like 
if (firstString.equals("")) to, let's say, make a toast if the user clicks the button without filling the EditText.